# Объясните, каким образом метод Arrays.fill() заполняет двумерный массив в цикле for each

Tags: java, массивы

```
int [][] array = new int[5][5];
                for(int [] ints: array) {
                    Arrays.fill(ints, 3);
                }
                System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
```

Вывод:

```
[[3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]]
```

Объясните, каким образом локальный ints изменяет значения в array.

Comment: "ведь ints должен принимать значение, а не ссылку" - ведь ints должен принимать ссылку, а не значение

Comment: Спасибо Айгр, я правда думал, что создаётся новый массив ints, в который копируются элементы array[0] и т.д., а оказалось ints = array[0] - просто ссылка на этот объект. Ещё раз спасибо за столь понятное и подробное объяснение для новичка!

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы пытаетесь выполнить `ints = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length)` находясь в теле цикла for each, вы меняете не саму ссылку на переменную array, а присваиваете ссылку на новый массив "локальной" ссылке ints.

А дело всё в том, что copyOf возвращает новый объект. Метод fill в свою очередь работает непосредственно с переданным объектом(ссылкой). Посмотреть это можно нажав ctrl + ЛКМ (для IDEA)

```
public static void fill(int[] a, int val) {
    for (int i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++)
        a[i] = val; // ничего не возвращает
}

public static int[] copyOf(int[] original, int newLength) {
    int[] copy = new int[newLength];
    System.arraycopy(original, 0, copy, 0,
                     Math.min(original.length, newLength));
    return copy; // возвращает массив
}
```

Следующий пример наглядно демонстрирует, что при попытке(в цикле for each) присваивания объекту новой ссылки - ничего не происходит.

```
   public class Person {
    public String name = "name";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.name = "1";

        Person[] massive = new Person[]{person};


        for (Person s : massive) {
            s = new Person();
            s.name = "haha!";
            // not change!
        }

        System.out.println(massive[0].name);
        System.out.println(person.name);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: ```
 int [][] array = new int[5][5];
                for(int [] ints: array) {
                    Arrays.fill(ints, 3);
                }
                System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
```
вот наглядный пример с таким выводом "[[3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]]", по вашему объяснению, значения должны меняться  только в локальном ints, но они также меняются в array. Почему?

Comment: deepToString не возвращает новый объект.

Comment: Причём здесь deepToString? Вы не понимаете вопроса?

Comment: Я не сразу заметил о чем речь из комментария. fill работает с переданной ссылкой. Вы передаёте ссылку на массив, а не ссылку на ints. Но если вы возвращаете ints новый массив, то это будет работать только внутри цикла.

Comment: Вы можете, исходя из моего примера написать статический метод, который принимает ссылку на Person, и присваивает ей новое значение. Это будет работать. Если вы попытаетесь присвоить новую ссылку внутри цикла, она будет уничтожена на следующем круге итерации.

Comment: Если мой ответ не помог вам, то я удалю его, чтобы он не вводил остальных участников в заблуждение. По моему всё описано довольно деревенски : если хотите что-то новое присвоить, форыч лучше не использовать.

Comment: Понятно, ints принимает ссылку на array и передаёт её fill(), а если писать ints = ... то это присваивает значение локальному ints [], который уничтожается после каждой итерации.
Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: не совсем так, у вас fill принимает ссылку на ints который указывает на конкретную область в памяти. Но если вы используете new [ ] , тобиж copyOf то создаётся новая ссылка, и в данном случае ints ссылается уже на неё, а не на исходный массив.